# C file input fscanf issue (crash)

Tags: c, file, input

As the title says i get a crash, when invoking beolvas(), of course. You probably get what I'm trying to do here, it's pretty simple too. I'm using mingw32 btw. Thanks for any help in advance!

```
typedef struct
{
    int kerSzam;
    int voteCount;
    char *lastName;
    char *firstName;
    char *party;
} Vote;

void beolvas(Vote t[], int *n)
{
    FILE *in;
    in = fopen("szavazatok.txt", "r");

    while(!feof(in))
    {
        fscanf(in,
               "%d %d %s %s %s\n",
               &t[*n].kerSzam,
               &t[*n].voteCount,
               t[*n].lastName,
               t[*n].firstName,
               t[*n].party
               );

        (*n)++;
    }

    fclose(in);
}
```

szavazatok.txt looks like this:

```
2 53 first last zed
1 5 first last pet
...
```

Comment: You must allocate some memory for char * members of the struct...

Comment: Any further help needed?

Answer (score 1):

As @Jean-Baptiste Yunès commented, need to allocate memory for strings.

Recommend testing the result of `fscanf()`.

```
void beolvas(Vote t[], int *n, int maxn) {
  FILE *in;
  in = fopen("szavazatok.txt", "r");
  if (in) {
    char lastName[50];
    char firstName[50];
    char party[50];
    int cnt = 0;

    // spaces not needed in format, but widths are very useful
    while(*n < maxn && (cnt = fscanf(in, "%d%d%49s%49s%49s", 
        &t[*n].kerSzam, &t[*n].voteCount, lastName, firstName, party)) == 5) {
      t[*n].lastName = strdup(lastName);     
      t[*n].firstName = strdup(firstName);     
      t[*n].party = strdup(party);     
      (*n)++;
    }

    fclose(in);
  }
}
```

As `strdup()` is non-standard, here is an implementation if needed.

```
char *strdup(const char *src) {
  if (src) {
    size_t size = strlen(src) + 1;
    char *p = malloc(size);
    if (p) {
      return memcpy(p, src, size);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```